# postgresql on docker eats all the cpu for query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query

I have a Django app with a PostgreSQL database. Everything was running smoothly until I moved the stack to Docker. Now, one of my big queries is running really slowly, and I noticed that the PostgreSQL container is eating up all the CPU for that particular query.

Here is the query on my local machine: https://pastebin.com/vUxAs5iU

And here is the query on the Docker container: https://pastebin.com/5TGba8Me

I noticed that I don't have the JIT analyzes on my local machine, and I'm not sure what the values in the Docker container mean or how to fix them. I've already tried increasing the CPU for the container, but it didn't help. What steps can I take to optimize my psql or query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information about the problem, please let me know.

Comment: to disable jit via sql you can use `alter system set jit to off; select pg_reload_conf();`

Comment: @SahapAsci oh thats fine, the problem is performance of my query, that you can see on the second link. im don't know why is it taking too long to execute

Comment: Because JIT is taking all of the time.  (That is why you should disable it.)

Comment: @jjanes Owwh, Thank you very much, worked.

Comment: @jjanes btw, i read that jit is useful for queries with a lot of joins and aggregations and complex queries, why is it bad in my case?

Comment: I've never seen JIT be more than slightly useful, but often find it to be devastatingly bad.  I don't know why people would say otherwise, perhaps the triumph of hope over experience.  If it ever reaches the point where the compilation doesn't need to be repeated on every execution but can be "stored" within the prepared statement, it would be worth a second look.  Until then, just turn it off and be done with it.

Comment: @jjanes Ok thanks again, helped a lot.